# How to use $this

Tags: jquery

I'm still learning jQuery and have the below code:

```
$("#panel1 .button").click(function(){
      $("#q1").hide();
      $("#success1").show();
    });

    $("#panel2 .button").click(function(){
      $("#q2").hide();
      $("#success2").show();
    });

    $("#panel3 .button").click(function(){
      $("#q3").hide();
      $("#success3").show();
    });
```

it looks redundant and I was wondering if this could be simplified using $this, or if there is another method, would appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

We can remove the duplicate code with a markup change.

First, lets modify the panels to have a common class ('panel') and an HTML5 data- attribute:

```
<div class="panel" data-panelid="1">
```

Repeat as needed for the other two panels. We can keep the unique ID (`id="panel1"`, etc) if you wish, but it isn't needed for this jQuery.

Next, we modify the selector to match the button in each of the panels:

```
$(".panel .button").click(function(){
```

Now in the click handler, we can check the data attribute and show/hide the correct elements:

```
var panelId = $(this).data('panelid')
$("#q" + panelId).hide();
$("#success" + panelId).show();
```

Now we have eliminated the duplicate code and used only one handler for all of the buttons. The completed jQuery looks like this:

```
$(".panel .button").click(function(){
   var panelId = $(this).data('panelid')
   $("#q" + panelId).hide();
   $("#success" + panelId).show();
});
```